# Liquibase run part of a changeset?

Tags: sql, liquibase

I have the below changeset but, I may want to add additional inserts in the future. It could be in the hundreds or thousands.

```
--changeset author:changesetid endDelimiter:;
INSERT INTO "MY_TABLE" (id, name) VALUES (1, 'bob');
INSERT INTO "MY_TABLE" (id, name) VALUES (2, 'jim');
INSERT INTO "MY_TABLE" (id, name) VALUES (3, 'mick');
```

I can't execute previous inserts because that would throw errors about that data already existing. Similarly, I don't want to have dozens or hundreds of individual changesets with their own combination of different inserts overtime. I would like everything consolidated under 1 changeset.

Maybe I could use some type of precondition with this attribute but, I wouldn't want to keep checking the table size (or have to update the precondition value) everytime I need to update the changeset.

```
--preconditions onFail:WARN
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

- create 2 changesets
  1st
  -insert your data to e.g MY_TABLE_TMP ( table without PK allowing duplicates)

  - add TRUNCATE at the beginning of this changeset and new inserts below,
    2st
  - your final changeset (sql script)
  - use a LOOP to get data from MY_TABLE_TMP and insert it with dynamic SQL into
    MY_TABLE
  - when error occures, ignore it and continue a LOOP
    Rafał

Comment: If I took this approach then, ideally I would want to drop the temp table afterwards. So say I have tens of thousands of records, well now my logs are going to be constantly filling up with thousands of individually failed records. All of the records that already exist will fail every time there is a new change in the changeset (if I enable `runOnChange:true`)

Answer (score 0):

Does your target database support an UPSERT or MERGE statement?  If so, you could make your SQL script so if the record is already found in the table nothing happens, and if not found the record is inserted.  This would make your script more complicated, but should achieve what you are looking for if you set the changeset to runOnChange.